# How to Install Android Apps to the SD Card by Default

Tags: adb, app2sd

I am following this tutorial for moving apps to sd card.

[How to Install Android Apps to the SD Card by Default](http://www.addictiveblogs.com/how-to-move-all-android-apps-to-sd-card-without-rooting-device/)

But My Default Location is not changing. And My Phone Memory is full and unable to install new apps.

Comment: Question is not comprehensible without reading external link. Please fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After Android Tools Update command `adb shell pm setInstallLocation 2` has been changed to `adb shell pm set-Install-Location 2`

Updated Tutorial can be founded [here](http://www.addictiveblogs.com/how-to-move-all-android-apps-to-sd-card-without-rooting-device/).