# I have an SD card and it still says that error in sufficient storage

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, app2sd

When I upgrade an Android application from Google Play, it gets downloaded, then the upgrade stops with the message

> Error: Insufficient storage available.

I have a 32 GB SD card so I want to download to the SD card but it only puts apps on the internal memory. How can I get apps to install to the SD card?

Comment: One of our eternal questions :) I've just re-tagged yours. Please see our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for first aid – and don't forget to check back and let us know if you've solved your issue.

Comment: Dang so the Sd card does not help? Well i eraese the apps and clear cache then it only takes like. 10 mb from it . There r some apps that i dont use wich take up alot of internal memory but i cant erease :( can u please help me out more And thanks for the first part that helped me understand scouple problems

Comment: Let's agree on "just plugging it in" does not help. Having it in, and doing something with it *explicitly* is a different thing: you can move some apps there, thus freeing up some internal memory. Advanced options, however, require root. Some hints are pointed out from the tag-wiki, e.g. [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2065/16575) Also make sure to always check the linked/related questions, which e.g. brings you to [How can I free up more space on my Android phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/3359/16575) and others ;)

Comment: @user49515 Please give the OS ,Device details. Without these details I cannot help you with a perfect answer which shall solve your problem

Comment: @AlE. Not really. Unlucky phrasing, but OP asks: "How can I get apps to install to the SD card?" – so it's rather a dupe of [How to Install Android Apps to the SD Card by Default](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42820/16575) ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what device you have or whether you  have rooted it so I'll show you a few options.

This should work for Samsung devices that still have the sock file manager.
http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1772970/set-default-download-location-card.html

This app will work if you have rooted your phone.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=frank.tools.defaultinstalllocationchanger&hl=en

If neither of those you should be able to do it this way but it may be  a tad tricky if your not very tech savvy
http://getandroidstuff.com/install-android-application-sd-card-mod-install-location/

Comment: It is an Acatel 4010

Answer (score -2):

you can go to settings-applications-preffered install location and change it from internal phone memory to SD card and yo apps will download just fine though if u remove the card,they will disappear....

the second option is quite long but its something to do with a software that allows you to allocate some of your memory card space to internal memory for example you allocate 5gb of your  memory card to internal memory and then u will have plenty of space to download your apps...Google about it